# changes in report library data source not reflecting in related reports

Tags: eclipse, birt

how to maintain single datasource url and username

I have gone through all your answers and questions, but after creating a library in report project and after making change in library data source it is not reflecting in all related reports...so please help me for this
I want to change my testing database to UAT ...and it is making problem in changing all data source in all reports with their parameters

Comment: Hello - could you please include more detail in the question, and some examples of what you have already tried to do to fix the problem?

Comment: Externalizing a datasource in a library actually works, you have made a wrong handling. For example you might have overridden some datasource properties in reports. Without a sample report (.rptdesign) it is not possible to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a little gotcha/flaw in the BIRT IDE:

As soon as you change a *DataSet* in a BIRT report, the designer UI overrides the *DataSource*'s properties. You should go into the advanced properties of the *DataSource* in your *.rptdesign and clear all local modifications (there's an icon to the right of the properties tab to do this).

Only then will the DataSource in the rptdesign inherit the props from the rptlibrary.

[image]